# Redirect to particular url after login

Tags: python, selenium, url, redirect

I have created a script to login on JIRA using python selenium. Now I want to redirect to given url just after login on JIRA. How can I do that.
Please provide sample code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using

```
driver.get("http://www.jira.com/")
```

to login to JIRA and wants to redirect after login or any certain point of time.

you can have

```
driver.get("http://www.some other url.com/")
```

to load the some other url in **same tab.**

In case you'd like to open in new tab :

```
driver.get("http://www.some other url.com/")
# some other code in the same tab
driver.execute_script('window.open("http://newURL.com","_blank");')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! after that, I'm trying to get the html data from the new address, like this:

src = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html')

But it's printing the first address.